# what kind of training should I seek?

Tags: human-resources, training, planning

I work for a medium size company, that has no HR plan for training.

My boss in this company agreed for training even though we are not sure on what kind of training and for what need as the timeline of the projects in the coming months are not clear.

Should I build a training plan based on

- What I assume will be the next projects in the coming months?
- Or should I plan the budget for training with my boss and wait for the potential projects before spending the company money?
- Or should I do training on things I work often like project management?

Any hints are more than welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: VTC -- what should I do type question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to add as well that on top of the things already mentioned that it would probably be helpful to consider setting training with your coworkers or people involved with you in your daily work. Either that or at the least opt for a training that gives a fair bit of feedback, if anything that feedback would help you establish a more concrete direction.

I suppose any training that would help you learn more things that would enable you to get more stakeholder buy-in in whatever you're working on would be worthwhile too.

Comment: Are you a management student by any chance? You make use of a lot of big words, but ultimately convey nothing useful.

Comment: @MaskedMan I was a management student a few years ago haha, so you're quite on point there.

Comment: @MaskedMan

Currently I'm working as a manager of a logistics company and have to deal with stakeholders like customs officials, brokers my clients and other government bodies. I've found from first hand experience that a lot of transactions or expansions really requires stakeholders to buy-in to what you're pitching to get approval. 

Certainly communication training and the like would help with that.

I respectfully disagree that I've conveyed nothing useful.

Comment: Hi @J.Bote, what you are saying at the end make sense, issue is stakeholder is like the wind, blowing one side one day or blowing  the other side, next day...

Comment: @MaskedMan it always depend on each point of view. J.Bote's answer is an useful one as well Joe's comment. Both of them provided something...

Comment: @JohnLegas oh I definitely agree that stakeholder interests can be quite volatile although in the end once you've gotten enough familiarity with the people in place it'd just be about how you'd frame/adjust your approach. I had this one project for the total conversion of one office space into a cold-storage room to save space and money on maintaining 40 foot refrigerated containers, and to be honest if I wasn't able to get the support I did from some of the parties involved my project proposal would've gotten swept off the table!